# Chrome extension localization in manifest not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to localize my extension's manifest file, of which the beginning looks as following:

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description":  "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "options_page": "__MSG_optionsPage__",
```

My message.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "appName": {
    "message": "The Great Grouper",
    "description": "The name of the application"
  },
  "appDescription": {
    "message": "Flooded with tabs? Store them easily into groups, reopen them whenever you feel like it.",
    "description": "The description of the application"
  },
  "popupPage" : {
    "message": "popup.html"
  },
  "welcomePage": {
    "message": "welcome.html"
  },
  "optionsPage": {
    "message": "options.html"
  },
```

the ***MSG_appName*** and ***MSG_appDescription*** work just fine, but not the ***MSG_optionsPage***, which throws me the following error:

> Could not load options page '__MSG_optionsPage__'.

What have I done that Chrome hates me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/common/extension_l10n_util.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr=Ss&rcl=1470309818&l=138) `LocalizeManifest` function localizes only text strings in the manifest file such as `name`, `description` and other descriptive labels, and web URLs, and CSS files. This is how [chrome.i18n API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n) works: **one local layout file** with message placeholders that are fetched from a corresponding language definition file in _locales folder.

Unfortunately, Chrome won't autolocalize your html files. So just make one `options.html` and use placeholders for all localizable strings it has, then fetch the localized values in options.js script manually.

- message.json:

  ```js
  "optionsLabel1": {
      "message": "This is a <strong>cool</strong> label"
  },
  ```
- manifest.json:

  ```js
  "options_page": "options.html",
  ```
- options.html:

  ```html
      .............
      <label id="label1"></label>
      .............
      <script src="options.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```
- options.js:

  ```js
  document.getElementById('label1').innerHTML = chrome.i18n.getMessage('optionsLabel1');
  ```

---

**In case you have a lot of localizable strings** the above primitive JS code could be enhanced to translate the current document on-the-fly replacing the placeholders with actual text before it's shown on the page:

- options.html:

  ```html
  <head>
      <script src="localizehtml.js"></script> <!-- should be the first -->
      <title tl="optionsTitle"></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      .............
      <h1 tl="optionsHeader"></h1>
      <label tl="html:optionsLabel1" for="input1"></label>
      <input tl="placeholder:optionsInput1" id="input1"></input>
      .............
      <script src="options.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```
- localizehtml.js:

  ```js
  new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      for (var mutation of mutations) {
          translateNodes(mutation.addedNodes);
      }
  }).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

  function translateNodes(nodes)  
      for (var node of nodes) {

          if (node.nodeType != 1) // skip if not ELEMENT_NODE
              continue;
          var tl = node.getAttribute('tl');
          if (!tl)
              continue;

          node.removeAttribute('tl');

          var hasTarget = tl.indexOf(':') > 0;
          var target = hasTarget ? tl.split(':')[0] : '';
          var msgId = hasTarget ? tl.split(':')[1] : tl;

          var message = chrome.i18n.getMessage(msgId);
          switch (target) {
              case 'html':
                  node.innerHTML = message;
                  break;
              case '':
              case 'text':
                  node.textContent = message;
                  break;
              default:
                  node.setAttribute(target, message);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

There are other methods of on-the-fly localization in HTML files, for example [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements).

Comment: I have to admit that I do not understand your answer completely. I have only one layout file, so why wouldn't chrome let me localize the options page?
Furthermore, it says in the documentation of the chrome.i18n API: 
"In manifest.json and CSS files, refer to a string named messagename like this:
\__MSG_messagename__"